# Redirection doesn't work if I'm logging into a site I never logged in before

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login

I'm on some page (https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags) of a site I have never logged into before. I click on the login button using my StackExchange OpenID creds. Instead of being taken to the page I was in before clicking the login button, I'm taken to the home page. This is despite the fact that I see the url https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2ftags#log-in before clicking the other (bigger) Login button.

**sidenotes**:

- I can reproduce both with Chromium 17 and Firefox 10.
- Clicking the `returnurl` link again works... takes me to https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags.
- For sites I have visited before, I automatically get logged in via clicking any clickable.

**update**: I no longer experience this issue.

Comment: There are actually quite a few login issues with OpenID across all of the stack sites.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for bringing this up. I cannot reproduce the issue in the current build of our network sites. If it remains an issue let me know!